# How to return an unchanged AR relation from a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def for_category(c)
      if c
        return where(:category_id => c.id)
      else
        return self
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I need to call it like this:

```
Item.where("created_at > ?", Time.now - 1.week).for_category(@category)
```

@category may or may not be null. In the case where category is null, I want the method to simply pass through and return the relation unchanged. Of course, return self simply returns the Item class.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried with `return scoped`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to return the Scope (as opposed to the Class itself) for further scope action? If so, then something like the following should work:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def for_category(c)
      if c
        return where(:category_id => c.id)
      else
        return scoped
      end
    end
  end
end
```

HTH

Comment: It was hard but I found this answer... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.for_category(c)
      conditions = {:category_id => c.id}
      conditions.delete_if {|key,val| val.blank? }
      self.where(conditions)
    end
end
```

Your **Item** is associated with **Category** ? If yes then you can simply get all item categories by `Item.where("created_at > ?", Time.now - 1.week).categroies` not need for above code.

Comment: where({}) is a working solution, though the above would fail if c.nil?

Comment: My full call looks something like: @person.friends_items.for_category(@category).search(@term).visible_on_site. I want to return items based on a category, a search term, and various other parameters defined variously as scopes and class methods.

Answer (score 1):

`#scoped` was deprecated in Rails 4. You can use `#all` to achieve the same effect:

```rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def for_category(c)
      if c
        return where(:category_id => c.id)
      else
        return all
      end
    end
  end
end
```